# Installing Config::Pit on Debian Wheezy

Tags: perl, debian, glibc, cpan

I am trying to install [Config::Pit](http://search.cpan.org/~satoh/Config-Pit-0.04/lib/Config/Pit.pm) from CPAN. Steps I did:

1. Download tar.gz from CPAN, untar
2. perl Makefile.PL
3. make install
4. make test

It failed with following error:

> Tried to use 'Config::Pit'.
>       Error:  Can't load '/home/git/cpan/local/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/auto/YAML/Syck/Syck.so' for module YAML::Syck: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/git/cpan/local/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/auto/YAML/Syck/Syck.so) at /usr/lib/perl/5.14/DynaLoader.pm line 184.
>    at /home/git/cpan/local/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/YAML/Syck.pm line 36.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/git/cpan/local/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/YAML/Syck.pm line 36.
>   Compilation failed in require at /home/git/google_net_spreadsheet/Config-Pit-0.04/blib/lib/Config/Pit.pm line 13.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/git/google_net_spreadsheet/Config-Pit-0.04/blib/lib/Config/Pit.pm line 13.

For my glibc, I checked with:

> ldd --version
>
> ldd (Debian EGLIBC 2.13-38+deb7u8) 2.13

My machine is running:

1. Debian 7.9
2. perl v5.14.2

Config::Pit requires glibc 2.14 (Mine is 2.13). How can I install it? Or how can I change dependency to glibc 2.13?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you show isn't directly related to Config::Pit.  Perl is failing to load [YAML::Syck](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::Syck), which is a dependency of Config::Pit.

You need to rebuild/reinstall YAML::Syck so it links with your glibc instead of a version you don't have installed.

Comment: I got it fixed by reinstalling YAML::Syck, thanks a lot! :)